# Client/Server sockets and ip addresses

Tags: sockets, delphi

If some of you have time and patience to help me with my problem, I would be thankful

I'm writing a simple delphi chat program(client/server sockets) which I want to transform into a mini-game. The code works well for localhost, but when i send the server or client to a friend, the client can't connect to the server.
Both of us are using routers. Also I think there is something with the way the ISP give us our IPs. What I mean is this: the "ipconfig" shows me I have 192.168.x.x ; but sites like "whatismyip.com" shows me a different address. And I don't use any VPN. The function TForm1.GetIPAddress shows me the 192.168.x.x one.

So, the question is this: how should I write the chat program? Which options do I have to connect a server and a client, given the above connection problem?

Here's the code for the server:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Win.ScktComp,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, winsock;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    server: TServerSocket;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Button3: TButton;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure serverClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure serverClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    Function GetIPAddress:String;
    procedure serverClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  server.Port:=strtoint(edit2.Text);
  server.Active:=true;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('server started');
end;


procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
server.Active:=false;
memo1.Lines.Add('server stopped');
end;


procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  Str:String;
begin
     Str:=Edit3.Text;
     Memo1.Lines.Add('server: '+Str);
     Edit3.Text:='';
     for i:=0 to server.Socket.ActiveConnections-1 do
      server.Socket.Connections[i].SendText(str);
end;


procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
edit1.Text:=getipaddress;
end;


procedure TForm1.serverClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
   memo1.Lines.Add('client connected '+socket.RemoteAddress);

end;

procedure TForm1.serverClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
   memo1.Lines.Add('client disconnected'+socket.RemoteAddress);
end;


procedure TForm1.serverClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
    memo1.Lines.Add('client: '+socket.ReceiveText);
end;


Function TForm1.GetIPAddress:String;
type
  pu_long = ^u_long;
var
  varTWSAData : TWSAData;
  varPHostEnt : PHostEnt;
  varTInAddr : TInAddr;
  namebuf : Array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
begin
  If WSAStartup($101,varTWSAData) <> 0 Then
  Result := 'No. IP Address'
  Else Begin
    gethostname(namebuf,sizeof(namebuf));
    varPHostEnt := gethostbyname(namebuf);
    varTInAddr.S_addr := u_long(pu_long(varPHostEnt^.h_addr_list^)^);
    Result := inet_ntoa(varTInAddr);
  End;
  WSACleanup;
end;


end.
```

And for the client:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  System.Win.ScktComp, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    client: TClientSocket;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Button3: TButton;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure clientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure clientDisconnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure clientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
client.Address:=edit1.Text;
client.Port:=strtoint(edit2.Text);
client.Active:=true;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
client.Active:=false;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if client.Active then  begin
      client.Socket.SendText(edit3.Text) ;
       memo1.Lines.Add('client :'+edit3.Text);
       edit3.Text:='';
  end
  else showmessage('not connected');
end;

procedure TForm2.clientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  memo1.Lines.Add('connected') ;
end;

procedure TForm2.clientDisconnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
     memo1.Lines.Add('disconnected') ;
end;

procedure TForm2.clientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
    memo1.Lines.Add('server: '+socket.ReceiveText)
end;

end.
```

Comment: your question has very little to do with Delphi, really. You'll need to use the external/WAN ip address (the one that "whatsmyip" gives you) to connect and configure your router for port-forwarding. Break your problem in pieces: first, get your program to work on your machine alone, client and server (that is the Delphi part of your problem); then you learn how to forward ports on your router.

Comment: This is not really a coding problem, it is a networking problem, and so it belongs on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: I get it, thanks guys. Will I be able to use the server/client with the help of hamachi like VPNs?

Comment: The client/server will work fine over any TCP/IP connection, whether it is VPN or not.  What is important is that you understand the layout of the network connection between the client and server so the client can connect to the correct hostname/IP. If the two machines are on the same LAN, even over a VPN, then the client can connect to the server's LAN IP. Otherwise, over the Internet, the client has to connect to the server's ISP-assigned public IP instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Both of us are using routers

You have to configure port forwarding rules on the server's router.

An inbound connection that passes through a router on the server side must be forwarded from the router's public WAN IP/Port to the server machine's private LAN IP/Port.  An outbound client on the outside can then connect to the server router's public IP/Port:

```
client -> internet -> router (104.34.x.x:YYYY) -> server (192.168.x.x:ZZZZ)
```

If the server's router receives a dynamic IP from an ISP (which is a common scenario in home networks), the IP will change periodically.  Rather than lookup the current IP manually whenever you want to connect, you can instead use a Dynamic DNS service (such as DynDNS, No-IP, Dynu, DuckDNS, etc) to create a static hostname that resolves to whatever the current IP happens to be (most routers have a built-in option to auto-update such services when the router's IP changes).  The client can then connect to the hostname instead of the router's IP directly:

```
client.Host := 'myDynDNShostname';
```

```
client -> DNS (what IP is "myDynDNShostname"?) -> "104.34.x.x"
then
client -> internet -> router (104.34.x.x) -> server (192.168.x.x)
```

Even if the ISP assigns a static IP instead of a dynamic IP, it is still a good idea to consider creating a static hostname for it, as hostnames tend to be easier to remember than IP addresses.

> Also I think there is something with the way the ISP give us our IPs. What I mean is this: the "ipconfig" shows me I have 192.168.x.x ; but sites like "whatismyip.com" shows me a different address.

That is perfectly normal.  `192.168.x.x` are private LAN IPs.  Running `ipconfig` on the server machine will show the IP that the router has assigned to the machine, not the router's public IP that the ISP has assigned.  Sites like "whatismyip.com" can only show the remote IP that is directly connected to them, which in this case is the router's public IP, not the server's private LAN IP:

```
browser (192.168.x.x) -> router (104.34.x.x) -> internet -> website
```

> The function TForm1.GetIPAddress shows me the 192.168.x.x one.

Because that is the IP that is assigned to that local machine by the router it is directly connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend should attempt to connect to the IP address which a site like whatismyip.com shows you. 192.168.x.x is your private IP address on your home network and cannot be directly reached from the Internet.

You will need to forward the port which your application uses on your ISP router to your local IP address to make this work. Google "port forwarding" to get started.

Bear in mind that, you are likely to be receiving a dynamic IP address from your ISP, which means that the IP will periodically change. You will therefore need to check what your IP is and provide your friend with the updated address just before connecting. An alternative is using a dynamic DNS service, which will allow your friend to connect to your application using a domain name instead of an IP address.